# Passing parameters to onClick function received via props without binding this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following two components:

```
class A extends Component {
   _onDelete(id) {
      this.props.deleteItem(id);
   }
   render() {
      return <B onDelete={this._onDelete}/>;
   }
}


class B extends Component {
   const onDelete= {this.props};
   let id = this.props.item.id;
   render() {
     return <div onClick={onDelete}>Hello</div>;
   }
}
```

I don't want to bind `this` (component B context) to the function, I only want to pass  `id` to `_onDelete`.

I tried these approaches:

1. Arrow function:

   ```
    return <div onClick={() => onDelete(id)}>Hello</div>;
   ```

`context` in `_onDelete` changes to B, and I don't have access to `this.props.deleteItem` anymore.

2. Passing by event:

   ```
   return <div onClick={onDelete} itemId={id}>Hello</div>;

   _onDelete(event) {
      this.props.deleteItem(event.target.itemId);
   }
   ```

`event.target.itemId` is `undefined`

How can I pass the `itemId` to `A`'s function, without binding `this` to it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A extends Component {
   _onDelete = (id) => {
      this.props.deleteItem(id);
   }
   render() {
      return <B onDelete={this._onDelete}/>;
   }
}
```

This way _onDelete will be available with A context. Just call it like this in B

```
class B extends Component {
   let id = this.props.item.id;
   render() {
     return <div onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(id)}>Hello</div>;
   }
}
```

Comment: the only difference between your code and my 1st approach is that you made the _onDelete an arrow function. How does that fix the issue ?

Comment: When writing _onDelete as arrow function , context remains that of A, And it  becomes available binded function with context A in component B. When you are passing non-arrow function, context remains undefined , thats why it was creating an issue. Javascript is lexical scoped language and arrow function keeps the context of the outer scope

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not quite correct, but I guess it's a problem here, not in your actual code. If you don't want to call `.bind(this)`, then you can pass an arrow function to `onDelete` which calls `_onDelete`:

```
<B onDelete={id => this._onDelete(id)}/>
```

The better solution would be to directly pass `this.props.deleteItem`, if that's all that `_onDelete` is calling:

```
<B onDelete={this.props.deleteItem}/>
```

In `B` you'd have to pass a custom function as well:

```
return <div onClick={() => onDelete(id)}>Hello</div>;
```